# Constant DC 12V, 2A from USB 3.0, SATA, Molex or other common PSU cable?

Tags: power-supply, led, usb, transformer, light

I'm in the process of trying to power a simple LED strip lights, spec 12V, 2A, through a PC rather than transformer. So far, I am debating the first stage.

After looking into USB 3.0, it can supply 1500MA, 12V which is sufficient, but will this remain constant under load through other devices?

Could a SATA or Molex PSU power line achieve this?

Perhaps there is another alternative, involving PC power outputs, thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course a Molex connection could. It can supply current right up until either of the wire or PSU is damaged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power connectors in a PC supply are directly connected to the power supply. There is no negotiation required, unlike USB.

A "Molex" 4 pin power connector or a SATA power connector do carry 12V multiple amps regularly. How consistent the 12V rail is depends on the load and quality of the power supply, but you shouldn't have any issue with that.

If this is in an active computer, it will only work when the computer is on. Or if you pull a computer power supply out, you will need to add a power enable switch, and a sufficient load for the supply to maintain power regulation.

Comment: But do note that if you don't have sufficient load on all the lines (a running PC does count) then the PSU may not be able to maintain regulation.

Comment: Perfect, I'm not sure why this slipped my mind, thank you for the advice!

Comment: @ReConnected I have the impression that SATA power connectors would be preferable: someone building a new PC will likely not need "Molex" connectors at all. Also, 1) SATA power connectors have a lower profile, if that could be a concern and 2) compare the hassle of actually connecting "Molex" and SATA power connectors.

Comment: I went for Molex, simply because I had the male and female connectors readily available and because my modular PSU has one free slot. All working perfectly, ready for integration into my desk build

Comment: There really isn't any issue with using either, for your purposes they are exactly the same. And the number of adapters to switch between molex and sata power connectors make it universal really.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about 12V from USB3 port. To make it to 12V, (a) the USB port must support variable voltage and conform to USB Power Delivery Specifications (USB PD), and (b) The port must be connected to a device that also conform to PD specifications. The protocol to make it happen is insanely complex and requires specialized integrated chips. I don't believe you can find this kind of USB3 port in your computer anytime soon.

Simply stick to the venerable internal 4-pin Molex, thanks to vast availability of connectors and variety of adapters.